# wso2 Error while installation

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am trying out wso 2 API manager and i get this error while running it (first time) :

```
[2017-09-20 14:33:56,538]  INFO - ConnectionStartOkMethodHandler Authentication
failed:Error processing data: java.io.IOException: Error looking up user javax.s
ecurity.auth.login.AccountNotFoundException: Invalid User : TestEmployee
```

I have looked at the config files, none of them have a value as test employee. Not sure from where wso2 installation reads this value. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: from the tags - can we assume you mean WSO2 API manager? what do you mean by "insallation" ? the first run?  aren't you connecting to the analytics server?

Comment: Yes trying to install api manager. And installation is running it for the first time. I have edited the question.